# Implementing geocoding of cities with my own DB or Google Maps API (or other solution)?

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder, fuzzy-search

I would like to know what people recommend for geocoding city inputs from users. I am trying to get the Lat/Long of a city a user inputs. One option is to utilize an API with such a service, i.e. Google Maps. Another I was considering was creating my own DB with an online dataset of cities and build an api around it myself. I think fuzzy search capabilities would be a requirement. Are there any thoughts on what the best way to implement this would be, or is it better to just go with a robust existing API? I am building my web app with Express/NodeJS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "Is your question about programming? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest solution is to go with the [Geocoding API from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), since it is built having in mind the integration with other services from Google Maps.

It has a very simple setup process, you just create your geocoder which you feed give the input which has passed through the [autocomplete from Places](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete)

Hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: But is it worth freeing myself of usage limits by creating my own api?

Comment: One of the main questions is wether you are going to have more than 2500 requests per day and more than 5 requests per second. If you do, then you might also want to consider that in order to build your own API you will need lots of data (where are you going to get that data from?). 
It should't be that hard building your own API, but only if really necessary.
Cheers!

Comment: Does it answer some of your questions?

Comment: This answer is an opinion.